# Puppeteer: performing element.click() inside page.$eval

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, browser-automation, playwright

The [`page.$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) and [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) methods both return a value if the `pageFunction` itself returns a promise (I suppose it is a very rare case with puppeteer if they would not, most puppeteer methods return promises).

> page.$$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])

**Documented use cases are all returning a value:**

```js
const divCount = await page.$$eval('div', divs => divs.length);
const options = await page.$$eval('div > span.options', options => options.map(option => option.textContent));
```

### Question

But can we use `page.$eval`/`page.$$eval` to perform methods that only interacts with the browser without returning usable value (like `element.click`), especially if for a very similar reason we consider it a [bad practice to use `Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map) when we aren't using the returned array?
I am curious because like this we could simplify scenarios where usage of [`Array.forEach` is problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

**It does work, but should we use it?**

```js
const clickAll = await page.$$eval('button', links => links.forEach(link => link.click()));
```

*Note:* Making it a `const` makes very less sense to me as we cannot use the `clickAll` reference anywhere else. I'd rather use it in itself without declaring it.

Comment: You could say that $$eval could return a value, but it doesn't need to.

Comment: Thanks @hardkoded! Meantime I also befriended with this solution :) So using it in itself (without declaring it as a `const`) should be fine, no expected side-effects?

Comment: No side-effects, you don't need the `clickAll`

Comment: Would you kindly post it as an independent answer below? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider this as a normal javascript `function` it could return a value or not, and you could use that return function or not. You don't need that `clickAll` variable.

```js
await page.$$eval('button', links => links.forEach(link => link.click()));
```